# Retorno com "|"

Tags: java

```
        public static final int corCombina(int cor1, int cor2) {
    if (!corValida(cor1)) return -1; //Se a cor1 não é válida, retorne -1...
    if (!corValida(cor2)) return -1; //Se a cor2 não é válida, retorne -1...

    return cor1 |cor2;
}
```

Encontrei num dos tópicos por aqui, mas como sou iniciante na linguagem, não entendi o tipo de retorno "`return cor1 | cor2`", como funciona isso?